# Why 1 of 8 self signed certificates does not work?

Tags: macos, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have set up the following self-signed certificates on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and made them trusted in Keychain Access:
    *.la.com     *.la.mx        *.la.es
    *.la.ca      *.la.com.ar    *.la.co.nz
    *.la.us      *.la.co.uk

However, for a reason that I can not understand the *.la.us certificate can not be trusted even though I follow the exact same process in creating it and trusting it.  In fact, if I do not trust and then trust each of the certificates they work and I get a green pad lock in Chrome 43.0.2357.132 (64-bit) "except" for the *.la.us.

For *.la.us I get:

> **Your connection is not private**
>   *Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.la.us (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET_ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*

If I click on *Advanced* I see:

> ***This server could not prove that it is www.la.us; its security certificate is from *.la.us.*** This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

If I proceed and click on the red padlock I see:

> ***Server's certificate does not match the URL.***

How is it the server's certificate does not match the URL when it clearly tells me it's www.la.us and the certificate is for ***.la.us**?

Is there something special about the domain **la.us**?  I have re-created the cert several times, re-entered the MAMP Apache virtual conf several times, and tried Keychain Access again and again (removing the cert in between).  Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: No.  I am not interested in registering la.us.  LA is the abbreviation we use for the test version of a site hence the use of self-signed certificates.

Comment: The real question here is why do you have 8 self-signed certificates? One is too many.

Comment: How is that the real question?  Why is one too many?  So I should not use any self-signed certificates.  Okay.  They are country specific domains.  How do you know without knowing anything about the project they serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are special rules for domains inside the .us name space and it looks like Chrome is enforcing these. From the [Wikipedia entry for .us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us#States_and_territories):

> A two-letter second-level domain is formally reserved for each U.S. state, federal territory, and the District of Columbia....

These rules also reflected in the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) where you find special entries for `la.us` and also various subdomains like `k12.la.us`.

These special rules suggest that there is no single owner of the `*.la.us` namespace and thus you should not be able to get a wildcard certificate for `*.la.us`. This is similar to the `uk` and `co.uk` namespaces where you can not get certificates for `*.co.uk` but only for `*.la.co.uk`. Note that not all of the rules in the public suffix list are used by all browsers to check the subject of the certificates.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Makes sense as to why just this one is problematic.  Would have been nice though if the Chrome developers that seem to have gone out of their way to check for this also took that extra little step and displayed a more informative error message.  Oh well....

Comment: @nikolaosinlight: Only public CA should issue certificates for public domains and it is expected that these CA know the rules  and never issue such a certificate. Thus in practice you don't need a detailed error description for this case and it simplifies the code if you just handle multiple errors the same way instead each separately. And simplified code is good, more so if it is used for security. If you are trying to simulate  a public CA it is expected  that you know all the rules. So don't expect detailed feedback on errors from the browsers.

Comment: On the one hand you say that CAs know the rules and would never issue such a certificate while on the other hand you say it simplifies the code to not present a detailed error message.  If that was the case then the browser shouldn't really care about cases like this one which involve US states as the CA should know better AND not checking for these additional cases would simplify the success path code.  If a browser wants to go out of its way to consider this an error and has done 99% of the job how much more complicate is it to present String B vs. String A.

Comment: @nikolaosinlight: Handling certificates in a secure way involves dealing with certificates which should not happen. It only involves presenting  a useful error message as far as it is of relevance to the user. What you expect is an error message relevant for the CA (i.e. pointing out errors by CA), not the user of the browser.

Comment: While I do get your point, after reviewing the Chrome messages it appears Chrome does outline the issue with NET_ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID which is sufficient.  I was merely expecting something that would help identify the issue with the certificate slightly better than "Server's certificate does not match the URL".  I now get that the latter message was due to the domain being considered invalid and thus did not match the URL.  Makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a follow up... I changed our domains to use l0.* instead of la.* and I would suggest that anyone using a test domain with SSL consult the public suffix listing and avoid the headaches of using any domain listed there.